# Partial sums of the logarithmic function

Tags: sequences-and-series

Consider the following

$$\int^a_0 \frac{1-x^k}{1-x }\, dx \text{ on the disk } |a|\leq 1.$$

This can simplified to

$$\sum_{n\geq 0}\int^a_0 x^n (1-x^k) \, dx $$

$$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{a^n}{n}-\frac{a^{n+k}}{n+k} $$

$$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{a^n}{n}-\sum_{n\geq k+1 }\frac{a^{n}}{n} = \sum_{n=1}^k \frac{a^n}{n}$$

This can also be thought of as partial sums of the logarithm function $\log(1-a)$.

So I defined the following

$$H_k^{(p)}(a)=\sum_{n=1}^k \frac{a^n}{n^p},$$

or the alternating partial sum

$$H_k^{(p)}(-a)=\sum_{n=1}^k \frac{(-1)^n}{n^p}a^n,$$

where $H^{(1)}_k(1)$ defines the harmonic numbers.

Some related functions are the following:

$$H_{\infty}^{(1)}(-a) = \log(1+a)$$

$$H_{\infty}^{(1)}(a) = -\log(1-a)$$

$$H_{\infty}^{(p)}(a) = \operatorname{Li}_p(a)$$

$$H_{\infty}^{(p)}(-1) = \eta(p)$$

$$H_{\infty}^{(p)}(1) = \zeta(p)$$

My question is whether this is already established in the mathematics community; that is, please refer me to an article where these partial sums are discussed in detail. Of course I know that $H_k^{(p)}(1)$ is already there , but I mean something with a parameter $a$. What made think of this is how often I encountered these partial sums.

Comment: Isn't that beginning obvious from $\frac{1-x^k}{1-x} = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} x^i$? No infinite sums required.

Comment: Also, probably not a good idea to use $H^{(p)}$ for an index, since that notation is often used for the $p$-th derivative of $H$.

Comment: And $H_\infty^{(1)}(a)=-\log(1-a)$, I believe.

Comment: Finally, the question of whether it is "established" is a bit vague. Obviously, $\mathrm{Li}_p$ is well known, and these functions are just the partial sum of the power series for that class of function.

Comment: @Thomas : thanks for your comments . $H^{(p)}_k$ is already used as the purpose I mentioned (It is called the generalized harmonic number). I only added the parameter $a$.

Comment: Yeah, when a sequence $H_k^{(p)}$ is fine notation. It becomes abiguous when it is a function $H_k^{(p)}(x)$.

Comment: Maybe I shall use something like ... ${}_p H_k(x)$